# Custom Post Type category nav isn't highlighting active category

Tags: php, css, wordpress, categories, custom-post-type

I used Types from wp-types to create my custom post type. I have category archive pages and individual post pages set up. The category navigation is highlighting the active category like it's supposed to on the category archive page, but not on the individual post page. What am I doing wrong here?

This is the code for the category list navigation:

```
<?php
    if (has_nav_menu('work_navigation')) :
        wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'work_navigation', 'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker(), 'menu_class' => 'nav work-navbar-nav']);
    endif;
?>
```

Category archive page here: http://designatwork.net/dawnew/category/financial/

Individual post page example here: http://designatwork.net/dawnew/work/212/

Comment: We can't see your localhost links. They're on your machine.

Comment: My bad, http://designatwork.net/dawnew/category/financial/ and http://designatwork.net/dawnew/work/212/